# Phonegap: What are the next steps after prepoulate the data base in phone gap app to retrieving data from sqlite in Phonegap, 

Tags: android, iphone, sqlite, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have implemented a **Phonegap** application **for iPhone** using ***jQuery mobile***. I have created a database using **sqlite**.

I have created my own data base 0000000001.db with some list of tables.

added it in to resources folder of xcode proj,

and **preloaded** this data base in to the application in to the *WebKit* folder.

when i cheack using sqlite manage it show all my data base tables and the content in the tables. But i want to show that content in the list views (table views)

I preloded the data base by following the [Gaurav S Tomar™ Tutorial Link](http://gauravstomar.blogspot.ca/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20GauravSTomarBootstrappingIntelligence%20%28Gaurav%20S%20Tomar%20%3a%20Bootstrapping%20Intelligence).

I dont know **`what are the next steps for data driven from the sqlite data base`**

Now I **want to retrieve the data from the database tables and populate it in to list views** (table views).

*`i was very new to the phone gap applications`*,

I dont know **`were (in wich files) we implement the code to retrieve data from data base from my sqlite file 000001.db`**

and **`how to display /populate that retrieved data base in list views`**

Any ***`detailed`*** suggestions / tutorials please? Thanks in advance..

---

I have added a .js file main.js in that i have implementedm

```
function queryDB(sql) {
    dbmanager.connect_database();
    dbmanager.db.transaction(function(tx){
                             tx.executeSql(sql,[],getResult,dbmanager.errorCB);
                             },dbmanager.errorCB);
}

function getResult(tx,results)
{ 

     for(var i=0;i<results.rows.length;i++){
    console.log(results.rows);
     console.log(results.rows.item[i]);
     }

}

$(document).ready(function()
                  {

                  $('#OneView').click(function() 
                                       {
                                       queryDB('select * from table');
                                       });



                  });
```

in that  **console.log(results.rows);**  prints like :  `{"length":3}`

**console.log(results.rows.item[i]);** prints `TypeError: Result of expression 'message' [undefined] is not an object.`

***But not the column values i have added in the table***

Comment: check this blog post http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/04/building-mobile-apps-with-html-and-a-local-database/. It uses backbonejs, it is a good tutorial on how to build organized app with backbone and jquery mobile with database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function queryDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}

// Query the success callback
//
function querySuccess(tx, results) {
  //console.log("Returned rows = " + results.rows.length);
// this will be true since it was a select statement and so rowsAffected was 0
if (!resultSet.rowsAffected) {
console.log('No rows affected!');
return false;
else
{
  //your list view code should be here.
}
}
```

use http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#SQLResultSet